# How can I exclude one word with grep?

Tags: regex, string, search, grep

I need something like:

```
grep ^"unwanted_word"XXXXXXXX
```

Comment: `grep -Rv "word_to_be_ignored" . | grep "word_to_be_searched"`

Answer (score 1128, accepted):

You can do it using `-v` (for `--invert-match`) option of grep as:

```
grep -v "unwanted_word" file | grep XXXXXXXX
```

`grep -v "unwanted_word" file` will filter the lines that have the `unwanted_word` and `grep XXXXXXXX` will list only lines with pattern `XXXXXXXX`.

**EDIT:**

From your comment it looks like you want to list all lines without the `unwanted_word`. In that case all you need is:

```
grep -v 'unwanted_word' file
```

Comment: what if I want to exclude N lines after the line with "unwanted word" as well? `-v 'unwanted_word' --after N` doesn't help because it INCLUDES the line and N lines after.

Comment: `-v` or `--invert-match` select non-matching lines. In your case `grep -v 'unwanted_word' file` or `grep --invert-match 'unwanted_word' file`.

Comment: I want to ignore one line above and one line below with matching pattern then How can i achieve it?

Comment: Awesome, I use this in git to quickly peruse the status of my repo, works like a charm: `git status -s |grep -v "folder_I_dont_care"`

Comment: Weird, it's the top answer, but in some cases it's wrong! If I want to find `sun`, except when it is `sunrise`, `grep sun|grep -v sunrise` skips line that contain both `sun` and `sunrise` at once, that is not what I want. `grep -P 'sun(?!rise)'` is much better.

Comment: @greene provided the key - excluding the term *in the same query*. I'm using `ag`, not `grep` per se, and I can't pipe one `ag` to another. What I needed was `(?!foo)` - thanks!

Comment: If you want to bring the regex power into the exclude pattern, just add `-E`. e.g. `grep -v -E "unwanted_pattern_in_regex" file`

Answer (score 127):

I understood the question as "How do I match a word but exclude another", for which one solution is two greps in series: First grep finding the wanted "word1", second grep excluding "word2":

```
grep "word1" | grep -v "word2"
```

In my case: I need to differentiate between "plot" and "#plot" which grep's "word" option won't do ("#" not being a alphanumerical).

Comment: You should reverse the order to get highlighting on `word1`.

Comment: I guess it would clarify to add a placeholder for the file name to that example

Comment: @MatthewRead I find it really more logic like this. First you're looking for occurences of "word1" then remove occurences found where there is also "word2"
The opposite is strange : first removing "word2" and then looking the word you want. Maybe it's just a point of view

Comment: @Nico There's no reason to continue sticking to you initial impulse after finding something more useful, though.  If you use this a lot, I would recommend creating a shell function that you can call (like `xnoty() { grep -v "$2" | grep "$1" }`) so you don't have to remember the construction.

Answer (score 47):

If your `grep` supports Perl regular expression with `-P` option you can do (if bash; if tcsh you'll need to escape the `!`):

```
grep -P '(?!.*unwanted_word)keyword' file
```

Demo:

```
$ cat file
foo1
foo2
foo3
foo4
bar
baz
```

Let us now list all `foo` except `foo3`

```
$ grep -P '(?!.*foo3)foo' file
foo1
foo2
foo4
$
```

Comment: Thanks for this, very useful! I would like to mention that The grep command is case sensitive by default

Comment: Note that `grep -v -P` also works without negation in regular expression.

Comment: **"if bash...you'll need to escape the `!`"**. Thank you thank you thank you! That's what I wanted!

Comment: However, this doesn't work in a way of `grep -P '(?!.*foo3)[a-zA-Z0-9]*' pattern, it won't find what you want to omit, but will find only the exact thing, so regexp is little useless for an exact phrases

Comment: The proposed pattern `(?!.*unwanted_word)keyword` only excludes lines where the `unwanted_word` starts *after* the `keyword` (possibly overlapped). To exclude *any* line that contains the `unwanted_word`, regardless of its position relative to the `keyword`, use `^(?!.*unwanted_word).*\Kkeyword` .

Answer (score 46):

The right solution is to use `grep -v "word" file`, with its `awk` equivalent:

```
awk '!/word/' file
```

However, if you happen to have a more complex situation in which you want, say, `XXX` to appear and `YYY` *not* to appear, then `awk` comes handy instead of piping several `grep`s:

```
awk '/XXX/ && !/YYY/' file
#    ^^^^^    ^^^^^^
# I want it      |
#            I don't want it
```

You can even say something more complex. For example: I want those lines containing either `XXX` or `YYY`, but not `ZZZ`:

```
awk '(/XXX/ || /YYY/) && !/ZZZ/' file
```

etc.

Comment: It appears to be much faster than the `grep -P` solution on big files.

Comment: @MBR `grep -P` means using Perl regexp, so loading that package is going to be way more expensive than a normal `grep`.

Answer (score 13):

Invert match using grep -v:

```
grep -v "unwanted word" file pattern
```

Answer (score 7):

grep provides '-v' or '--invert-match' option to select non-matching lines.

e.g.

```
grep -v 'unwanted_pattern' file_name
```

This will output all the lines from file file_name, which does not have 'unwanted_pattern'.

If you are searching the pattern in multiple files inside a folder, you can use the recursive search option as follows

```
grep -r 'wanted_pattern' * | grep -v 'unwanted_pattern'
```

Here grep will try to list all the occurrences of 'wanted_pattern' in all the files from within currently directory and pass it to second grep to filter out the 'unwanted_pattern'. 
'|' - pipe will tell shell to connect the standard output of left program (grep -r 'wanted_pattern' *) to standard input of right program (grep -v 'unwanted_pattern').

Answer (score 5):

The `-v` option will show you all the lines that don't match the pattern.

```
grep -v ^unwanted_word
```

Answer (score 0):

I excluded the root ("/") mount point by using `grep -vw "^/"`.

```
# cat /tmp/topfsfind.txt| head -4 |awk '{print $NF}'
/
/root/.m2
/root
/var

# cat /tmp/topfsfind.txt| head -4 |awk '{print $NF}' | grep -vw "^/"
/root/.m2
/root
/var
```

Answer (score -4):

I've a directory with a bunch of files. I want to find all the files that DO NOT contain the string "speedup" so I successfully used the following command:

```
grep -iL speedup *
```

Comment: From the man page: "-L, --files-without-match  Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which no output would normally have been printed.  **The scanning will stop on the first match.**" (Emphasis by me) So beware of this!