# grep Command for Files with "String1" AND NOT "String2"

Tags: linux, string, macos, terminal, grep

I went through the answers on -

1. [Grep regex NOT containing string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411616/grep-regex-not-containing-string)
2. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/10/grep-or-and-not-operators/

but I'm still facing some issues to find all the files in a directory which contains "String1" but not "String2".

I tried the following command, but along with the correct result, it also returns the files containing both the strings -

```
grep -Hrn "String1" . | grep -v -Hrn "String2"
```

Kindly correct my mistake.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128434/find-files-containing-one-string-but-not-the-other

Comment: Remove the `-Hrn` from your second `grep`: `-r` will make it search recursively in the current dir (basically ignoring your previous `grep`), `-H` will make it show filenames (which it can't do if it's taking input from stdin), and `-n` will make it show line numbers (which will be different in the output of your first `grep`). The first `grep` is correct, and will get the correct filenames and line numbers, but the second `grep` is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-L` flag:

```
-L, --files-without-match  print only names of FILEs containing no match
```

---

First you find the files that *doesn't* contain "String2", then you run on those and find the ones that *does* contain "String1":

```
$ grep -L "String2" * | xargs grep -nH "String1"
```

Comment: I believe the `-L` option is a nonstandard extension, but if you have it, good for you.

Comment: @Maroun
Pls tell me the slight modification as well, so that it works for the directories. Right now, it is giving an error for the sub-directories as - 

"grep: dir: Is a directory"

Comment: @BhavukMathur Add the `-r` flag again.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy with Awk.

```
awk 'FNR==1 { if (NR>1 && one && !other) print prev; one=other=0; prev=FILENAME }
    /string1/ { one=1 }
    /string2/ { other=1 }
    END { if (one && !other) print prev }' list of files
```