# Is there a way to exclude certain interfaces/address from dbus-monitor output?

Tags: monitor, dbus

From the manpage of the `dbus-monitor` command, I know that I can use some command line arguments like `dbus-monitor "type=..., sender=..., interface=..."` to specify the type/sender/interface etc I am interested in.

However, for the situation that there is a few program that has heavy dbus traffic that I am not interested in, is there an option to filter out the output of that interface/program?

THX

Comment: you could always filter in the syslog config.  i can't remember the details, but i *think* you can match for arbitrary strings.

Comment: ?? I don't think it has anything to do with `syslog` though. I am just talking about the `dbus-monitor` command.

Comment: oh, sorry - i thought you were trying to reduce the amount of data appearing in a log somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dbus-daemon routes messages using message matching rules. You cannot have something like "message unmatching" rules, the specification does not support something like this. See [here](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#message-bus-routing-match-rules) for more information.

To get the desired filtering behavior I would suggest using `grep` on the output of `dbus-monitor`. Check [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538253/grep-how-could-i-exclude-one-word) for more information.